# Want to make entire TD cell an anchor

Tags: jquery, anchor, html-table

I have a `<table>` where each `<td>` holds only an anchor.  I'd like users to be able to click anywhere in the cell to visit that reference rather than only on the anchor text itself.  I imagine there must be a bit of jQuery to do this easily.  Can anyone help?

*Edit:* To complicate things, my `td`'s have some top and bottom padding.  A `display: block;` rule doesn't seem to work in this case.  I've edited the example:

CSS:

```
table#mainmenu td {
    padding: 9px 8px 5px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 1px dotted; 
    text-align: left;
}
```

Example:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></td>
  <td><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="foobar.html">FooBar</a></td>
  <td><a href="barfoo.html">BarFoo</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @BoltClock: because [jQuery is great and does all things](http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif).

Comment: @BoltClock Because I didn't realize it was so simple.  :)

Comment: @Rich - No worries, I've also over thought problems like this before. It's much easier than jQuery in this case to use CSS.

Comment: @Rich - Display: block is simply making the A tag expand to the entire contents of the TD (minus the TD's padding). You'll still need to use display: block, you just need to account for the padding of the containing TD as well.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just make the A tag `display: block`.

```
table td a {
  display: block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/6VZ8t/

Or, if you insist on jQuery:

```
$('table td a').css('display','block');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/a2EAz/

**EDIT**

Since I wasn't able to find a CSS-only way to select a parent TD of a child A, this solution does use jQuery:

```
function doTablePadding() {
    $td = $('table td');
    $td.has('a').css('padding','0');
    padding = $td.not(':has(a)').css('padding-top') + " ";
    padding += $td.not(':has(a)').css('padding-right') + " ";
    padding += $td.not(':has(a)').css('padding-bottom') + " ";
    padding += $td.not(':has(a)').css('padding-left') + " ";
    $td.children('a').css('padding',padding);
}
doTablePadding();
$('table tbody').append("<tr><td>Stuff</td><td><p>Other stuff</p></td></tr>");
$('table tbody').append('<tr><td><a href="foo.html">Foo</a></td><td><a href="bar.html">Bar</a></td></tr>');
doTablePadding();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/Mekjg/1

Note that this is running from `$(document).ready();`.

**EDIT 2**

As **mu is too short** notes, negative margins should work (and no jQuery):

```
td {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #0ff;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
td a {
    display: block;
    margin: -5px;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #f0f;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/seqpp/

Comment: Thanks, jQuery is overkill in this place.

Comment: Actually, this didn't work as I expected.  I have padding in my cells and the block display doesn't wrap to them.  (Sorry this is more complicated than I thought).

Comment: It's not necessary in this case is all; much easier to use CSS. For instance, if you used jQuery, you'd then have to make sure and call the jQuery code on page load and then any time later if the information updated.

Comment: Also, you could take the padding off the TD cells and add it to the A tag instead.

Comment: @Jared: posted, yes, pushing the padding to the A tag does work too, but I'd like the padding on the cells even if they don't contain an A tag.  Sorry I didn't realize it would be this complicated.

Comment: @Rich: You want to set the `<a>`s to block display, add negative margins to overcome the `<td>`s padding, then put the padding inside the `<a>`: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/seqpp/

Comment: @mu - Thanks, I was thinking about negative margins... (really) I was just hung up on selectors.

Comment: @Rich - If you need to use jQuery for some reason, I updated the jQuery code to account for all paddings, not just padding-left. If you do use this, you will need to call it each time you change the table itself (for instance, when using append()).

Comment: Thanks @Jared and @mu.  I went the CSS way.

Comment: This does not seem to work at all with browsers in 2023

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
   $('td').click(function(){
    window.location = $("a", this).attr("href");
  });
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rarTf/

Answer (score 0):

just make the css as

table td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

and make script as

$('table td').click(function(){
    window.location.href=$('a',this).attr('href');
});